# Oracles supporting Polygon Zkevm

Tags: nodes, chainlink, oracles, external-api

Are there any oracles present at the moment supporting smart contracts to securely retrieve data from conventional APIs (not data feeds) through HTTP(S) GET and POST calls.

We have looked into Witnet, Api3-Airnode and Pyth.

Witnet supports the mentioned functionality only on testnet
Airnode currently doesnt suppport Zkevm node deployment via chainapi
Pyth has support for only price datafeeds.

Thanks

Comment: Chainlink Data Feeds are also available on Polygon zkEVM.